# Avoid consecutive figures in two columns layout

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

Is there a way to tell LaTex to avoid putting figures consecutively in a single column. Instead, I want to distribute the figures in the top of the columns and/or other pages in the same way (only top), and only if it is really necessary (or otherwise stated) to put them consecutively.

Comment: `twocolumn` document mode does not allow the traditional floats with optional float placement specifiers `[htbp]`. The only specifier that works is `[H]` from the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float). Even then things are not 100%. The only "movable" float is given by the starred versions `*`. As such, layouts of your requirement have to be manually adjusted. See the [UK TeX FAQ entry on "Floats in multicolumn setting"](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=mcfloat).

Comment: @Werner: Is there a way to avoid consecutive figures in a one column environment?

Comment: As I understand it, consecutive means that the figures literally follow one another in the typeset output. So, if this is the case, the only way around it in `onecolumn` mode is to space the images out in the actual text and use the "here" float specifier (like `[h]` or actuall `[H]`). Using any one of `[tbp]` will create a FIFO list of images, that can be flushed together if there's enough room on a page, thereby making them appear consecutively.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, but this question is about figures being on top of page. So, with the `[t]` constraint, how to force figures to not follow each other? What I was getting at is that we can't solve this problem with multiple columns, until we can at least solve it with a single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To control the positioning of *single-column* figures (i.e. the non-starred version) in a two-column layout, you may adjust the `topnumber` counter which controls the maximum number of floats at the top of the column (and is also used for figures with `onecolumn`).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\setcounter{topnumber}{1}% default value is 2

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice - if you only want the figures at the top in columns, add `\setcounter{bottomnumber}{0}` (default value is `1`) as well.