# Why my table doesn't appear on the page I place it?

Tags: tables, floats, includegraphics, subfig

I have thw following code in latex but my table appears after the images. In the code the code for table is written before the code for imgaes. How can I make the table appear before the images?

```
Some text here.
 \begin{table}[h]
         \caption{.}
        \centering
%       \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
            \small
            \begin{tabular}{rrlrrrrrr}
            &&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Metoda propusa}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Metoda Canny}\\
                \hline
                Img. &Imagine  BSBD& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acuratetea}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coeficientul  Dice}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Acuratetea} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Coeficientul Dice}\\ 
                \hline
                1 & 103070.jpg &   0.9017 &0.1789  &0.8298 & 0.1767\\
                 2 & 104055.jpg & 0.9238 &0.2694  &0.8530 &0.1864\\
                 3 & 106025.jpg & 0.9391 &0.2594 &0.9487 &0.2145\\
                 4 & 108004.jpg & 0.8563 &0.3738 &0.7539 &0.2291\\
                 5 & 108005.jpg & 0.8213 &0.1583 &0.7878 &0.1477\\
                 6 & 108082.jpg & 0.8572 &0.0816 &0.8296 &0.0885\\
                 7 &  109053.jpg &0.9166 & 0.1930 &0.8273 &0.1682\\
                8 &  113044.jpg & 0.8967 &0.2802 &0.7997 &0.1675\\
                 9 & 123057.jpg &0.9250 & 0.1407 &0.8370 &0.14906\\
                 10 & 130026.jpg & 0.8718 &0.0879 &0.8162 &0.0770\\
                 11 & 160068.jpg & 0.8691 &0.0968 &0.8519 &0.1166\\
                  12 & 16077.jpg & 0.8822 &0.2614 &0.7978 &0.1866\\
                  13 & 163014.jpg & 0.9182 &0.2778 &0.8629 &0.2020\\
                 14 & 163085.jpg &0.8387 &0.1144 &0.8113 &0.1778\\
                  15 & 167062.jpg &0.8928 &0.2264 &0.9528 &0.2685\\
                  16 & 196027.jpg & 0.9358 &0.2596 &0.9142 &0.2472\\
                  17 & 247003.jpg & 0.8020 &0.1571 &0.7488 &0.2289\\
                  18 & 253027.jpg & 0.8421 &0.3308 &0.8348 &0.2869\\
                  19 & 291000.jpg & 0.7741 &0.1585 &0.6862 &0.1015\\
                 20 & 296007.jpg & 0.9638 &0.1927 &0.8589 &0.1119\\
                  21 & 304034.jpg &0.7805 &0.2185  & 0.7024 & 0.1522\\
                 22& 326038.jpg  &0.8490 &0.3106  &0.7688 &0.1652\\
                 23& 326085.jpg &0.8739 &0.1824 &0.7880 &0.09560\\
                 24& 38092.jpg &0.8941 &0.4058 &0.8103 &0.2324\\
                 25 & 41033.jpg &0.9461 &0.2834&0.8725 &0.1701\\
                 26&  42049.jpg &0.9506 &0.5688&0.9260 &0.3500\\
                 27& 43074.jpg &0.9004 &0.2247 &0.8771 &0.1814\\
                 28& 69015.jpg &0.7865 &0.3290 & 0.7787 &0.2924\\
                 29& 69040.jpg &0.7371 &0.0876  &0.7128 &0.1199\\
                 30 & 8023.jpg &0.9478 &0.0895  &0.8611 &0.1016\\
                \hline 
            \end{tabular}
%       \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table} 
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/testImages/8023.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/testImages/groundTruth8023.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/testImages/imageResult8023.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{images/cannyImage/canny8023.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}     
    \caption{.}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)

Comment: Please make your code compilable and please clarify: Do you use a tco column documentclass? Your use of `figure*` makes me guess you do, but your table appears to be a lot wider than a usual column in a single column document. Please clarify that.

Comment: You tagged your question using `subfig`, from your code fragment I guess, you're using `subcaption` instead.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31880/avoid-consecutive-figures-in-two-columns-layout#comment62789_31880 might also be interesting.

Comment: The _only_ purpose of the `table` environment is to specify that the content is not part of the main document flow and can be inserted ("floated") to another page to help with page breaking.   `tabular` does not have to be in ` table`